# Talend / Alfresco 4.0 connector?

Tags: alfresco, etl, talend, cmis

As far as I can tell, this project http://knowledge.openwide.fr/Main/AlfrescoETLConnector
only supports Alfresco 3.3 and under. Are there any Talend connectors for Alfresco 4.0? We have so much development work in 4.0 that we don't even want to think of rolling back to 3.3, and would like to use an ETL like Talend to load batches of files into Alfresco.

Are there other ETL tools we should consider that have Alfresco 4.0 connectors? Can we use any Talend / CMIS compliant connector? Suggestions on products to look at? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried getting it working with 4.0?

Comment: I have not, because the searches I've done turned up posts saying it won't work. But you're right, I should at least give it a shot.

Comment: I'm working on this again next week and will update this with what I find. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

This is Ronny from XeniT.
If you want to load documents and meta-data, you might consider 
http://www.xenit.eu/move2alf/
You can integrate this with Talend, but it allows easy and fast migration of content into Alfresco.

Answer (score 2):

On the [Talend Exchange](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/index.php) you can find various extensions e.g. custom components, which you can install in your TOS.

The exchange provides a [CMIS input component](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/index.php?eid=501&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1) that is able to access CMIS-compliant content repositories (like Alfresco) via CMIS SQL.

I also worked on an output component (tCmisOutput), which can create/update content. But this component has not been published yet. Since you are looking for way to load files into Alfresco, I will publish it in the next days on Talend Exchange or send the source code if you contact me via email.

Answer (score 2):

I've recently published new Advanced CMIS components for Talend (in alpha version).
You can download it on [Talend Exchange](http://www.talendforge.org/exchange/index.php?eid=733&product=tos&action=view&nav=1,1,1)
Source code and documentation are available on [Github](https://github.com/julienboulay/talend-cmis-components)
[cmis](/questions/tagged/cmis)[talend](/questions/tagged/talend)[etl](/questions/tagged/etl)[alfresco](/questions/tagged/alfresco)[nuxeo](/questions/tagged/nuxeo)

Comment: Thanks. I'll have some time to check this out next week.

Comment: Nice work, Julien!
Here the new link to the Github (old one is not working anymore):
https://github.com/Ekito/talend-cmis-components

Comment: Thanks, I've seen your work on the CMIS Input component and it works well. We can contribute together to common cmis components if you want.

Comment: Hehe, good idea. Maybe we find somemore interesting use cases. :-)
I like your Talend-Wizard plugin very much. Has this been done for a special project or customer? best regards

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of the Talend CMIS component developed by Ekito is on GitHub

https://github.com/Ekito/talend-cmis-components

However it will not work with Talend version 6 right out of the box. I've created a blog post describing the fix you need to apply to the component here:

http://www.datalytyx.com/fixing-the-cmis-component-issue-in-talend-6-gated/

Comment: Thank you for sharing on Stackoverflow in this thread. Following your post I have been onto the blog post, read it and found the fix makes sense. I can suggest to create a notification on the company's Jira system: adding a link to the blog post will enable to see the message and determine if this can be updated in a future version. Is that something you can do on your end? Thanks, best.

Answer (score 1):

Since last year, the Alfresco ETL Connector for Talend has been updated to support Alfresco 4.1, as said in the README :

https://github.com/OpenWide-SI/alfresco-etl-connector

Regards